# How to match parameter and replace the value after "=" separator

Tags: linux, perl

the perl one liner command to replace Value in file is simple:

```
perl  -i  's/oldval/newval/g' file.txt
```

but what should be the perl one liner syntax in case we want to replace the  value on specific parameter ( value is after "=" seperator

**Example**

We want to match the **VIP_IP** string and replace the value after "=" separator with other value as **192.17.200.100**  ( with perl one liner syntax )

```
more file.txt

VIP_IP=172.17.200.15

if [[ $VIP_IP = $HOST_IP ]]
then

.
.
.
```

Expected results

```
more file.txt

VIP_IP=192.17.200.100

if [[ $VIP_IP = $HOST_IP ]]
then

.
.
.
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### Changing an IP Address

```
perl -p -i -e 's/VIP_IP=[[:digit:].]+/VIP_IP=192.17.200.100/' file.txt
```

Or:

```
perl -i -pe 's/(VIP_IP=)[[:digit:].]+/${1}192.17.200.100/' file.txt
```

Or, if the new IP is in a shell variable:

```
export ip=192.17.200.100
perl -i -pe 's/(VIP_IP=)[[:digit:].]+/${1}$ENV{ip}/' file.txt
```

#### Changing a Name

Suppose our file looks like:

```
$ cat file.txt
VIP_IP=192.17.200.100
HOST=James
```

And, suppose that we want to change the (alphabetic) word after HOST.  In that case:

```
export host=Timothy
perl  -pe 's/(HOST=)[[:alpha:]]+/${1}$ENV{host}/' file.txt
```

If we wanted to change an alphanumeric word, as opposed to a pure alphabetic word:

```
export host=Timothy
perl  -pe 's/(HOST=)[[:alnum:]]+/${1}$ENV{host}/' file.txt
```

If we wanted to be still less restrictive and change any and all characters following `HOST=`:

```
export host=Timothy
perl  -pe 's/(HOST=).*/${1}$ENV{host}/' file.txt
```

Comment: not so good because I not know the IP - 192.17.200.100 , the code must find the IP itself ( VIP_IP value can be any IP )

Comment: @maihabunash Please don't speak in riddles.  Where will you get  the new IP from?  Is it in a shell variable? or a file?  or what?

Comment: what I need is perl line liner command to replace any current IP with the new IP ( the new IP must be variable )

Comment: so is it possible to change the 192.17.200.100 to variable?

Comment: just another remark variable can few IP as "123.2.21.1   4.5.5.3" and so on

Comment: ok , that fine , last question in order to replace string/s or word  what should be in place :digit: ? ( +1 for you )

Comment: @maihabunash The answer is updated with more alternatives.